# Telegram Bot profile with calendar

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, telegram-bot

I am writing a bot profile. After the answer, the following question should be asked. In one of the steps you need to select a date. I use a ready-made calendar. But after choosing a date, the next question is not asked, but the script does not crash, only waits for input and throws the Exception defined in the code below. How to fix that would bring up the next question "What is your name?". Thank. Here is the part of the code that includes the previous calendar question and the next question:

```
def process_Personenanzahl_step(message):
    try:
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        user = user_dict[chat_id]
        user.carModel = message.text

        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True)
        itembtn1 = types.KeyboardButton('1')
        itembtn2 = types.KeyboardButton('2')
        itembtn3 = types.KeyboardButton('3')
        itembtn4 = types.KeyboardButton('4')
        itembtn5 = types.KeyboardButton('5')
        markup.add(itembtn1, itembtn2, itembtn3, itembtn4, itembtn5)

        msg = bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Qun', reply_markup=markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, check_calendar_messages)

    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message, 'ooops!!')



calendar_1 = CallbackData("calendar_1", "action", "year", "month", "day")


def check_calendar_messages(message):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()  # Get the current date
    bot.send_message(
        message.chat.id,
        "Selected date",
        reply_markup=telebot_calendar.create_calendar(
            name=calendar_1.prefix,
            year=now.year,
            month=now.month,  # Specify the NAME of your calendar
        ),
    )


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data.startswith(calendar_1.prefix))
def callback_inline(call: object) -> object:
    # At this point, we are sure that this calendar is ours. So we cut the line by the separator of our calendar
    name, action, year, month, day = call.data.split(calendar_1.sep)
    # Processing the calendar. Get either the date or None if the buttons are of a different type
    date = telebot_calendar.calendar_query_handler(
        bot=bot, call=call, name=name, action=action, year=year, month=month, day=day
    )
    # There are additional steps. Let's say if the date DAY is selected, you can execute your code. I sent a message.
    if action == "DAY":
        msg = bot.send_message(
            chat_id=call.from_user.id,
            text=f"You have chosen {date.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')}",
            reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove(),
        )
        print(f"{calendar_1}: Day: {date.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')}")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_fullname_step)


def process_fullname_step(message):
    try:
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        user_dict[chat_id] = User(message.text)


        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove(selective=False)

        msg = bot.send_message(chat_id, 'What is your name?', reply_markup=markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_fullname_step)

    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message, 'ooops!!')
```

Comment: ”Telegram bot with calendar” thats not a question. what is your actual question?? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How run bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_fullname_step) without msg arg?